# User registration on PHP with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I create a simple code for user registration, and when user submit the data was not recorded to MySQL.

Here is my logic code

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST["user"];
    $password = $_POST["pass"];
    $confirmPassword = $_POST["repass"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    $username = stripcslashes($username);
    $password = stripcslashes($password);
    $confirmPassword = stripcslashes($confirmPassword);
    $email = stripcslashes($email);

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbtest');
    if($con->connect_error)
    {
        echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('connection to database failed!')</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO 'user'('Username', 'Password', 'Email') VALUES('$username', $password', '$email')");
        echo "You are successfully registered!";
    }
    $con->close();
?>
```

Is there something that I missed?

Comment: What errors are you getting? - Turn on error reporting and start debugging.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Does the code stop somewhere, does it give you an error? Have you attempted to debug it already?

Comment: does this `echo "You are successfully registered!";` work?

Comment: when user submit their data it not giving any error, and the `echo "You are successfully registered!";` work just fine @hungrykoala

Comment: It is not a doublicate, because there are more Errors as only the single quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove the single quotes arround the column names and table names, because mysql will interpret these as strings, not as table/column names

```
  $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `user` (Username, `Password`, Email) VALUES('$username', $password', '$email')");
```

Also you should use prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection.

You should ask for errors after executing SQL Statements ([mysqli_error()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp))

`User`and `password` are reserved words in mysql. To escape These , use backticks or better rename the table and the column. For more informations about keywords read the mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

Comment: I've tried to remove the quotes, and the data still not recorded to database

Comment: @AlbertHenderson then use backticks

Comment: I've change using backticks for the table name and column, and not work too

Comment: @AlbertHenderson has you added `mysqli_error, to see what error message you get?

Comment: OK i just added `mysqli_error($con)` and it show up the error `Error Description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '', 'albert@henderson.com')' at line 1` @Jens

Comment: Hey dude now it works just fine, and user inputted data now recorded, thanks a lot for your explanation @Jens

Answer (score -2):

**This should work**, its safer now and your passwordconfirm works.

```
<?php
$username        = $_POST["user"];
$password        = $_POST["pass"];
$confirmPassword = $_POST["repass"];
$email           = $_POST["email"];

$username        = stripcslashes($username);
$password        = stripcslashes($password);
$confirmPassword = stripcslashes($confirmPassword);
$email           = stripcslashes($email);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbtest');
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO user ('Username', 'Password', 'Email') VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')", $username, $password, $email);

if($password == $confirmPassword)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query)
    if($result)
    {
        echo "You are successfully registered!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Something went wrong.";
    }
    $con->close();
}
else
{
    echo "The passwords you entered didn't match.";
}

?>
```

I used **sprintf()** to make the query and checked it with **mysqli_query()**.
It also checks if the passwords match.
Regards - Raul.

Comment: It doesn't work. single qoutes arround column names